# jQuery displays AJAX/API data twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

This seems to be a common issue I can't find a clear answer on.

I'm using an API to pull JSON data with an AJAX call. The data I return displays twice in the console and in the DOM.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function(){
    var $dataHere = $('.dataHere');
    var company = "square205";
    var key = "xxx";
    var action = "time_entries.json?callback=?";
    console.debug()
    $.ajax({
          url: 'https://' + company + '.teamwork.com/' + action,
          headers: {"Authorization": "BASIC " + window.btoa(key + ":xxx")},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        // billableType: "billable",
        page: "1",
        success: function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(i, projects) {
            $dataHere.append('<div class="item"><p>Project name: ' + data["time-entries"][0]["project-name"] + '</p>' +'<p>Task name: ' + data["time-entries"][0]["todo-item-name"] + '</p>' + '<p>Hours: ' + data["time-entries"][0]["hours"] + '</p></div>');
            console.log(data);
          });
        }
      });
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>S205 TIME LORD</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
<body>
<span class="timeLordTitle">
  <img class="logo" src="http://square205.com/wp-content/themes/square205/images/logo-white.png" alt=""><strong> TIME LORD</strong></span>
<div class="btn">
    <div class="hexagon">
      <div class="hexTop"></div>
      <div class="hexBottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</br>
<div class="dataHere"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you are using `$.each`. that loops over every property of your `data` object. If you have more than 1 property in that object its going to get called multiple times.

Comment: You have used data["time-entries"][0], **0** which should be variable and also, $.each iterate over each DOM element. So, if you have more than one element it will print output more than once. [Jquery Each](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: Provide sample data and expected results as per [mcve]

Comment: @PatrickEvans The issues is not that it displays more than one item. It is intentional that I am requesting multiple objects. The issue is that it displays an unnecessary duplicate of all data requested.

Comment: @singhpradeep Please see my reply to Patrick Evens

Comment: @charlietfl Unfortunately, this is as minimal as it gets. I can't provide the code with the private API token. The data requested simply displays as duplicates in the console and the DOM - it doesn't matter if I've requested 1 or 100 items, it duplicates the data I've asked for.

Comment: No reason you can't provide a sample that reproduces problem. How are people supposed to help when they can't reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

I figured it out. The API calls back the JSON data returning two properties: STATUS and the data found in the time-entries object. This means the loop iterated the amount of properties available (2). I fixed the code by changing it to this line so it only loops through one property.

```
$.each(data["time-entries"], function(i, projects) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are hard coded 0th index. use `i` instead `0`

```
  $.each(data, function(i, projects) {
            $dataHere.append('<div class="item"><p>Project name: ' + data["time-entries"][i]["project-name"] + '</p>' +'<p>Task name: ' + data["time-entries"][i]["todo-item-name"] + '</p>' + '<p>Hours: ' + data["time-entries"][i]["hours"] + '</p></div>');

          });
```

Comment: `$.each` is looping over `data` properties, not `data['time-entries']`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to unbind the click as below?

> $('.btn').unbind('click').click(function(){
>   ......
>   }

Comment: I gave it a shot. Same result and no errors. I did move the console.log(data) outside the $.ajax call and it displayed only once.